# Getting Authorization error while using Google My Business API in ASP.NET Core Web API project

Tags: oauth-2.0, asp.net-core-3.1, google-my-business-api

I am trying to call Google My Business API from my ASP.NET Core Web API project as shown here below:

```
using HighrangeModel;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.MyBusinessAccountManagement.v1;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using System.Net;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses;

namespace HighrangeAppliances.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class GMBController : ControllerBase
    {
        [Route("~/api/GetGMBAccount")]
        [HttpGet]
        public  HttpResponseMessage GetGMBAccount()
        {
            var ClientId = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com";
            var ClientSecret = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
            string[] scopes = new string[] { "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/business.manage" };

            try
            {
                UserCredential credential =  GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                new ClientSecrets {
                    ClientId = ClientId,
                    ClientSecret = ClientSecret,
                },
                scopes,
                "user",
                CancellationToken.None).Result;

                // TokenResponse contains the tokens, access token expiry time etc.
                TokenResponse token = credential.Token;

                var service = new MyBusinessAccountManagementService(new BaseClientService.Initializer() { HttpClientInitializer = credential });

                var accountsListResponse = service.Accounts.List().Execute();

                return new Response<string>("Listed Succesfully", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(accountsListResponse), HttpStatusCode.OK);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return new Response<string>(ex.Message, "", HttpStatusCode.ServiceUnavailable);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

On the website https://code.google.com/apis/console I have registered my application, set up generated Client ID: and Client Secret to my app and tried to log in with Google. Unfortunately, I got this error:

[image]

Now I am using localhost to check the code and under Authorized JavaScript origins: `https://localhost:44386`, Authorized redirect URIs: `https://localhost:44386/api/GetGMBAccount` are registered.

Comment: What does the request details section show?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add the redirect URI to your google cloud settings under the Client OAuth where you view your client secret, [as mentioned here](https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/basic-setup#:%7E:text=Add%20the%20following%20as%20a%20valid%20redirect%20URI%3A).

**But note:** If you are trying to implement server to server, this is not the right path to follow; you need to authenticate server-side not client-side, as is happening here.